# exploitation of the server banner information provided in the response header

Tags: security

Is it possible to exploit the banner information provided in the response header to get sensitive information about the server?
A typical response looks like below

```
**HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 19 Apr 2011 09:23:32 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: tracking=tI8rk7joMx44S2Uu85nSWc
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1067
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN” “http://
www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”><html xmlns=“http://
www.w3.org/1999/xhtml” ><head><title>Your details</title>
…**
```

I am trying to know wether "Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0" can be used to exploit the vulnerability present in the server or to get some sensitive information about the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All kinds of information *can potentially* be useful to a potential attacker. Your example could be one small part of a larger reconnaissance effort.

As [Jedi mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40758781/336648), the info you've provided can give a clue about potential weaknesses in the web server itself. Another thing to keep in mind though, is what the server tells you about the company's choice of architecture in general; if they are using a web server from Microsoft, chances are they will be using a database system from them too (and possibly mail servers and other stuff too).

There`s no guarantee of this of course, but it may provide a starting point for further investigation which may in turn reveal other weaknesses, such as SQL injection vulnerabilities (which are probably the most prevalent class of vulnerabilities in websites and web applications today).